# R: dataframe turns into vector after deleting columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
  L1 2020 NA
1  1    0  0
2  2    1  0
3  3    1  0
```

I want to delete first and last column, to get dataframe like this:

```
2020 
1  0 
2  1 
3  1
```

I tried:
1)

```
df <- df[,-c(1,ncol(df))]
```

or 2)

```
df <- subset(df, select = -c(1,ncol(df)))
```

For both I get result:

```
[1] 0 1 1
```

So I guess it changed data frame into vector. How can I delete these columns to keep it as a data frame?It is important for me to keep it like this. I don't have this problem when there are more columns. It changes only when one column is supposed to be left.

Comment: You can give `[` a `drop = FALSE` argument to tell it to not "drop" unneeded dimensions. `df[,-c(1,ncol(df)), drop = FALSE]` will work. (This is a confusing bit about subsetting data frames).

Comment: Alternately, when subsetting columns, if you use `[` without a row argument, you will always get a data frame result. So `df[-c(1,ncol(df))]` will also work. (This is treating the data frame like a list of columns - which is how the data frame class is implemented.)

Answer (score 1):

After specifiing the columns in the square-brackets, add `,drop=FALSE` right after it.

The `drop`-argument is `TRUE` by default and you are struggling with this default.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10)
df[,1] #R simplifies to a vector via implicit drop=TRUE default
df[,1,drop=FALSE] #dataframe-structure remains
```